# Make sure module is ran even though it is not imported anywhere

Tags: python

In my Flask app, I have a file `controllers.py` with `some_process` in it:

```
class SomeProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subscribers = []

    def subscribe(self, subscriber):
        self.subscribers.append(subscriber)
        return subscriber

    def notify(self, data):
        for subscriber in self.subscribers:
            subscriber(data)

some_process = SomeProcess() # I want it to be single instance for the whole app
```

In another module `notifications.py` I want to subscribe to this process:

```
from controllers import some_process

@some_process.subscribe
def create_notification(data):
    pass
```

The problem is that I never import `notifications.py` anywhere in the app, therefore this module is never ran and subscription never happens.

I used decorator in the first place because I want to avoid having one centralized place in the app where functions are imported and subscribed to `transactions_process`. I would also rather avoid just importing the `notifications.py` module somewhere to make it "seen" by the app, as such bare imports are highlighted by our linting tools and prone to be removed by someone by mistake.

Is there any good way of solving this?

Comment: If it's never used do you need to import it at all? `some_process` seems like it only needs to exist if it's being used (and therefore imported) somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like what they want to do is initialise this globa state. @barciewicz can't you do that in your application's entry point?

Comment: @101: `create_notification` is meant to be used - I want to create a notification after `some_process` is done. I just wanted to pepper any other functions that needs to be ran in my codebase with the `subscribe` decorator instead of registering everything in one place.

Comment: @ndc85430: I probably could, but would would be a good pattern for that, given I don't want a "bare" import of the module nor one centralized place of registering subscribers?

Comment: `importlib.import_module` will look fine for your linter and is unlikely to be accidentally removed later, especially if you add a short comment nearby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would invert your dependencies here. You're creating a Pub/Sub, but there's some boilerplate you'll have to write to make that Pub/Sub work.

I would use a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) here (because I find it easy to read) and initialize it as part of your main loop (before instantiating the flask app and serving).

```py
# pubsub.py
class PubSubBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__some_process = SomeProcess()

    def with_subscriber(self, subscriber):
        self.__some_process.subscribe(subscriber)
        return self

    def build(self):
        return self.__some_process


class SomeProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subscribers = []

    def subscribe(self, subscriber):
        self.subscribers.append(subscriber)
        return subscriber

    def notify(self, data):
        for subscriber in self.subscribers:
            subscriber(data)
```

Then drop the decorator from notifications.py and instead write a separate subscriptions.py

```py
# subscriptions.py
import pubsub as mod_pubsub
import notifications

pubsub = mod_pubsub.PubSubBuilder()
             .with_subscriber(notifications.create_subscription)
             # and however many more you have
             .build()
```

Then in main.py

```py
# main.py

# before your main loop:

from subscriptions import pubsub
# etc...
```

You can perhaps register that pubsub object in your flask global state and have other modules do some sort of service discovery to find it (`if 'pubsub' in flask.g: ...` or etc, my Flask is a bit rusty so that might be wrong)

Comment: The tradeoff here is that your subscription logic is separate from your application logic. Depending on where you stand on this issue that might be a pro or a con. It DOES, however, mean you have to be quite careful about circular imports, depending on how "smart" your notifications.py is.